# defaultdict(lambda: set()) how to add

Tags: python, set, defaultdict

Sample MVR code:

```
w_1, w_2 = None, None
tokens = ['hello', 'world', 'type', 'contexts', 'hello', 'again', 'world']
self.type_contexts = defaultdict(lambda: set())
for word in tokens:
    self.type_contexts[word] += {(w_2,w_1)}
# Update context
w_2 = w_1
w_1 = word
```

I want the type_contexts defaultdict to map word -> {(w_2, w_1)} but I'm not sure how to fill these in as sets. I keep running into TypeErrors like TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'set' and 'set'

or else using set function add() in my type_contexts line:

```
self.type_contexts[word].add({(w_2,w_1)})
```

results in TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

I understand why I get these errors but I'm not srue how to fix them keeping the lambda: set() defaultdict

Comment: Note you can simply define `defaultdict(set)` without the `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `add` expects an *element* (hashable) not a set, if you want to add a new set to an existing one use update:

```
a = set()
a.add(1)
a.update({2})
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
{1, 2}
```

The first line illustrates how to use `add`, it your case it will be:

```
self.type_contexts[word].add((w_2, w_1))
```

The second shows how to add a set to an existing one, so you can change your call to:

`self.type_contexts[word].update({w_2, w_1})`.

Although I would not recommend the use of update with a set of single element.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are combined with the `|` operator, not `+`, and thus you want `|=` instead of `+=`.  Alternatively, since you're adding a set of only one element, you could instead just `add` that element:

```
self.type_contexts[word].add((w_2,w_1))
```